# Return from format inside loop

Tags: loops, format, lisp, common-lisp

I'm a Lisp noobie having some difficulty understanding how `loop` and `format` work when combined.

This works as I expect:

`(loop for i upto 2 do (format t "~a" "Badger")) ==>
BadgerBadgerBadger
NIL`

This does not:

`(loop for i upto 2 do (format nil "~a" "Badger")) ==>
NIL`

Why does this second loop not return `BadgerBadgerBadger` ? What code must I write to give this return value?

Comment: The first loop doesn't *return* BadgerBadgerBadger either.  It *returns* `nil`.  So does the second one.  The first one, because `format` is writing to standard output, *prints* Badger three times.  The second one, because format is returning a string which is then discarded (because you're not saving it), doesn't produce any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the first parameter of the `format` function, called *destination* (see the [manual](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_format.htm)):

> If *destination* is a string, a stream, or `t`, then the result is nil. Otherwise, the result is a string containing the ‘output’

In the first case, `format` writes to the standard output (you see the three "Budger") and returns `NIL`. But you do not see *that* value, but the value returned by `loop`, which is `NIL`. In fact, no clause in `LOOP` is present  (like `RETURN`) to return something different from `NIL`.

In the second case, `format` returns the string, *but* the value of the loop is again `NIL`, which is result of the whole form.

If you want to return the result of the format, you could, for instance, write:

```
(with-output-to-string (s)
   (loop for i upto 2 do (format s "~a" "Badger")))
```

In this way, the `format` function "write" to the string stream `s`, which is returned by `with-output-to-string`.

Comment: Alright so far so good, so how do I rewrite my loop so it will return the result of format?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to "return" a value from format.

Answer (score 3):

There's an important difference between returning a value and printing a value.  Sometimes this can be confusing in the REPL, because return values are printed by default:

```
CL-USER> (+ 1 1)    ; form *returns* 2
2                   ; and return value (2) is printed
CL-USER> (let () 
           (+ 1 1)  ; (+ 1 1) still returns 2, but
           nil)     ; the return value of the (let ...) is NIL
NIL                 ; so NIL is printed
```

Now, format can do some different things, depending on its first argument.  If its first argument is **t**, or a stream, then it writes output to the stream and returns nil:

```
CL-USER> (format t "hello")
hello                         ; printed output
NIL                           ; return value from format

CL-USER> (let ()             
           (format t "hello") ; will print "hello"
           42)                ; but the whole form returns 42
hello                         ; printed output
42                            ; printed return value
```

When format is called with **nil** as a first argument, it returns the output that it generates as a string:

```
CL-USER> (format nil "hello")
"hello"                           ; return value, not printed output

CL-USER> (let ()
           (format nil "hello")   ; returns "hello"
           42)                    ; but the whole form returns 42
42                                ; printed return value
```

Now, you can **collect** results from loop, and it sounds like you want to use **format** to generate a string, and then collect those strings:

```
CL-USER> (loop for i upto 2 collect i)
(0 1 2)

CL-USER> (loop for i upto 2 collect (* 8 i))
(0 8 16)

CL-USER> (loop for i upto 2 collect (format nil "string number ~a" i))
("string number 0" "string number 1" "string number 2")
```

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation, the behaviour of format with various first arguments isn't what is causing my confusion, but you have helped me pinpoint it more exactly - why is it that loop does not return the string generated by format as a returned value within it?

Comment: You're generating not *one string*, but three: one in each iteration. Loop doesn't automatically collect the results of `do` clauses; that's just not how it's defined. Have you encountered something that led you to believe otherwise.

Comment: I wrote something which worked as I indicated above (i.e. format operations within a loop which were returned as one string on loop completion). Between the REPL and C-c C-c (which seem to store independent versions of functions on Aquamacs) this was achieved by something with the structure `(let (...) (loop for i up to ... when ... do (format nil "~a" ...) else do (format nil "~a" ...)))` as I wasn't trying other approaches. On reload the code produced `NIL` instead. I am unsure what is missing for the desired behaviour, it isn't with-output-to-string or collect, as I didn't know of them.

Comment: Further to the above, my understanding is that inside constructs like loop in which many forms can be executed, the return value should be the last evaluated form, as in your (let (format nil "hello") 42) example. Why is it that the loop doesn't return the result of format occurring 3 times (in the example in my question) even though it does correctly concatenate the strings, as seen when the first argument to nil is changed to t instead of nil?

Comment: @Sam Because `LOOP` have explicit keywords for accumulating data (`sum`, `collect`, ...).

Comment: @Sam *"(i.e. format operations within a loop which were returned as one string on loop completion)"*  I think that's the key misunderstanding;  the first loop did *not* return a string;  it *printed* a string three times, and then *returned* nil.  A functions side effects and its return values are distinct things.  E.g., **print** returns its argument.  That means that you can do `(+ (print 1) (print 2))`.  You'll see 1 and 2 *printed*, but that form *returns* 3.